# I'm having trouble with a loop, my error involving &&

Tags: java

My directions are to write a code (in java) that finds an code between 1,000 and 9,999 (any 4 digit number), that meets four qualifications:

1. All four digits are different.
2. The digit in the thousands place is 3 times the digit in the tens place.
3. The number is odd.
4. The sum of the digits is 27.

This is what I have so far. I'm getting an error under my `//loop` section:

```
C4PP10.java:27: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'"
```

is the error that appears.

In my head, `&&` simply means "and", am I using it improperly?

This is for my intro to java class homework BTW.

```
public class C4PP10
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        int first=1;
        int second=0;
        int third=0;
        int fourth=0;
        int total = first * 1000 + second * 100 + third * 10 + fourth;
        boolean fourDifferentDigits = false;
        boolean thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace = false;
        boolean odd = false;
        boolean sum = false;
        boolean correctAddress = false;

        //loop
        while (correctAddress = false)
        {
            fourth = fourth + 1;
            if (fourth == 10)
            {
                fourth = 0 && third = third + 1;
            }//end if
            if (third == 10)
            {
                third = 0 && second = second + 1;
            }//end if
            if (second == 10)
            {
                second = 0 && first = first + 1;
                total = first * 1000 + second * 100 + third * 10 + fourth;
            }//end if
        }//end loop


        //testing
        if ( first != second && first !=third && first !=fourth && second !=third &&                 second !=fourth && third != fourth )
        {
            fourDifferentDigits = true;
        }//end if

        if (first == third*3)
        {
            thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace = true;
        }//end if 

        if (fourth%2 != 0)
        {
            odd = true;
        }//end if

        if ( first + second + third + fourth == 27 )
        {
            sum = true;
        }//end if

        if (fourDifferentDigits=true && thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace=true && odd=true   && sum=true)
        {
            correctAddress = true;
        }//end if

        if (correctAddress = true)
        {
            System.out.println("The Riddler plans to strike " + total + " Pennsylvania     Avenue!");
        }

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: `&&` is a boolean operator, not a funny way of spelling the English conjunction "and". It does far, far less than the English conjunction.

Comment: Just thought I'd add, the intent of my loop is to basically add 1 to the fourth digit, then when the fourth digit reaches 10, add one to the third digit and reset the fourth digit to 0, counting up essentially, thanks again to anyone who looks into my code for me!

Comment: Yes.  You want a `;` where you have `&&`

Comment: `while (correctAddress = false)` should be `while (correctAddress == false)` **or** `while (!correctAddress)` **or** `while (correctAddress != true)`. One equals is assignment.

Comment: in your `while` loop, you are using ony one `=`, so it makes an assignment of `false` to the `correctAddress` variable, thus ending the loop since the assignment is `false`. If what you want is a comparison then you have to use `==`

Comment: @RobertoLinares however as he's comparing boolean, he write it just as `while (correctAddress) {` and prevent a typo with the use of `=` and `==`

Answer (score 0):

So many formatting errors, make sure for comparison use `==` instead of `=` for Boolean statements and to use indentation for readability.
Only use `&&` in a logic statement, not as an addition to a statement. You can also define multiple variables at the start by using a comma (`,`), instead of having to type `int` every time.

```
public class C4PP10
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        int first = 1, second = 0, third = 0, fourth = 0;
        int total = first * 1000 + second * 100 + third * 10 + fourth;
        boolean fourDifferentDigits = false, thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace = false;
        boolean odd = false, sum = false, correctAddress = false;

        while (correctAddress == false) // or while (!(correctAddress))
        {
            fourth = fourth + 1;
            if (fourth == 10)
            {
                fourth = 0;
                third = third + 1;
            }                
            if (third == 10)
            {
                third = 0
                second = second + 1;
            }
            if (second == 10)
            {
                second = 0 
                first = first + 1;
                total = first * 1000 + second * 100 + third * 10 + fourth;
            }
        }


        if (first != second && first != third && first != fourth && second !=third && second !=fourth && third != fourth)
        {
            fourDifferentDigits = true;
        }

        if (first == third * 3)
        {
            thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace = true;
        }

        if (fourth % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd = true;
        }

        if (first + second + third + fourth == 27)
        {
            sum = true;
        }

        if (fourDifferentDigits == true && thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace == true && odd == true && sum == true)
        {
            correctAddress = true;
        }

        if (correctAddress == true)
        {
            System.out.println("The Riddler plans to strike " + total + " Pennsylvania Avenue!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not to confuse OP with another operator, but the second to last if-statement can be replaced with `correctAddress = fourDifferentDigits & thousandsPlaceX3TensPlace & odd & sum`. Really, all the if-statements can be removed, and the variables assigned to the checks.